# Performance issue while finding min and max with functional approach

Tags: ios, swift, functional-programming

I have an array of subviews and I want to find the lowest tag and the highest tag (~ *min* and *max*). I tried to play with the functional approach of Swift and optimized it as much as my knowledge allowed me, but when I do this:

```
let startVals = (min:Int.max, max:Int.min)
var minMax:(min: Int, max: Int) = subviews.filter({$0 is T2GCell}).reduce(startVals) {
        (min($0.min, $1.tag), max($0.max, $1.tag))
}
```

I still get worse performance (approximately 10x slower) than good ol' **for** cycle:

```
var lowest2 = Int.max
var highest2 = Int.min
for view in subviews {
    if let cell = view as? T2GCell {
        lowest2 = lowest2 > cell.tag ? cell.tag : lowest2
        highest2 = highest2 < cell.tag ? cell.tag : highest2
    }
}
```

To be totally precise I am also including snippet of the measuring code. Note that the "after-recalculations" for human readable times is done outside of any measurement:

```
let startDate: NSDate = NSDate()

// code

let endDate: NSDate = NSDate()

// outside of measuring block
let dateComponents: NSDateComponents = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!.components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitNanosecond, fromDate: startDate, toDate: endDate, options: NSCalendarOptions(0))
let time = Double(Double(dateComponents.nanosecond) / 1000000.0)
```

My question is - am I doing it wrong, or this use case is simply not suitable for functional approach?

---

**EDIT**

This is is **2x** slower:

```
var extremes = reduce(lazy(subviews).map({$0.tag}), startValues) {
    (min($0.lowest, $1), max($0.highest, $1))
}
```

And this is *only* **20%** slower:

```
var extremes2 = reduce(lazy(subviews), startValues) {
    (min($0.lowest, $1.tag), max($0.highest, $1.tag))
}
```

Narrowed and squeezed down to very nice performance times, but still not as fast as the for cycle.

---

**EDIT 2**

I noticed I left out the `filter` in previous edits. When added:

```
var extremes3 = reduce(lazy(subviews).filter({$0 is T2GCell}), startValues) {
    (min($0.lowest, $1.tag), max($0.highest, $1.tag))
}
```

I'm back to **2x** slower performance.

Comment: `subviews.filter()` creates an intermediate array, so that *may* be a performance problem. Try `lazy(subviews).filter()` instead.

Comment: It doesn't let me use reduce on it - *LazySequence<FilterSequenceView<S>> does not have a member named reduce* ...

Comment: You have to use the reduce *function* instead. Something like `reduce(lazy(subviews).filter(...), startVals) { ... }`.

Comment: Aha, now it's getting more interesting :-) It actually did help, from 10x slower down to 2x slower.

Comment: And when I remove the map, I'm almost on the same performance as with the for cycle.

Comment: Which map? I cannot see a `map()` in your question. (I used `map()` in my second comment, but that was an error and is fixed now.)

Comment: It's there now, I edited it (see EDIT) - I first used your first recommendation, the one as you said that you removed.

Comment: Btw, you can compute the time difference simply with `let time = endDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(startDate)`. – Did you test in in Release mode (with optimizations)? – You should also check with Xcode 6.3 (beta) which brings a lot of performance improvement.

Comment: If the type of `subviews` is `[AnyObject]`, this could be the source of the problem.  Can you try the performance of `var minMax:(min: Int, max: Int) = (subviews as? [T2GCell])?.reduce(startVals) {
    (min($0.min, $1.tag), max($0.max, $1.tag))
} ?? startVals` - I can't reproduce your case easily but if it's faster I have a theory why...

Comment: It's faster, but produces wrong output.

Comment: Sorry, I realize now it's possible you have entries in that array that aren't of type `T2GCell` – in which case that approach wouldn't work.  Nonetheless, I suspect the source of the slowness is calling `AnyObject.tag`, whereas in your for loop you are using `if let as?` then calling `T2GCell.tag` which could be a big performance difference.

Comment: possibly `var minMax:(min: Int, max: Int) = subviews.reduce(startVals) { prev, next in
    (next as? T2GCell).map {
        (min(prev.min, $0.tag), max(prev.max, $0.tag))
    } ?? prev
}` will do it

Comment: Alternatively, switch your `for` version to use `is` not `as?`, use `view.tag`, and see if that degrades performance in a similar fashion.

Comment: 1) Your advice on other minMax is nice, faster, but not as fast as the for cycle. And for 2) even when I change `as?` for `is`, the functional approach is never faster.

Comment: Are you testing in release mode?  I'd be surprised if the `for` version is still faster then, but will be faster in debug.  Here's some sample code that demonstrates the perf differences:  https://gist.github.com/airspeedswift/5e2944cec6a823d1fbd0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In optimized builds, `reduce` and `for` should be completely equivalent in performance.  However, in unoptimized debug builds, a `for` loop may beat the `reduce` version, because reduce will not be specialized and inlined.  The filter can be removed, eliminating an unnecessary extra array creation, however that array creation is going to be pretty fast (all it is doing is copying pointers into memory) so that is not really a big deal, eliminating it is more for clarity.

However, I believe part of the problem is that in your `reduce`, you are calling the `.tag` property on `AnyObject`, whereas in your `for` loop version, you are calling `T2GCell.tag`.  This could make a big difference.  You can see this if you break out the filter:

```
// filtered will be of type [AnyObject]
let filtered = subviews.filter({$0 is T2GCell})

let minMax:(min: Int, max: Int) = filtered.reduce(startVals) {
    // so $1.tag is calling AnyObject.tag, not T2GCell.tag
    (min($0.min, $1.tag), max($0.max, $1.tag))
}
```

This means `.tag` is going to be dynamically bound at runtime, potentially a slower operation.

Here's some sample code that demonstrates the difference.  If you compile this will `swiftc -O` you'll see the statically-bound (or rather not-quite-so dynamically-bound) `reduce` and the `for` loop perform pretty much the same:

```
import Foundation

@objc class MyClass: NSObject {
    var someProperty: Int
    init(_ x: Int) { someProperty = x }
}
let classes: [AnyObject] = (0..<10_000).map { _ in MyClass(Int(arc4random())) }

func timeRun<T>(name: String, f: ()->T) -> String {
    let start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    let result = f()
    let end = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    let timeStr = toString(Int((end - start) * 1_000_000))
    return "\(name)\t\(timeStr)µs, produced \(result)"
}

let runs = [
    ("Using AnyObj.someProperty", { 
        reduce(classes, 0) { prev,next in max(prev,next.someProperty) } 
    }),
    ("Using MyClass.someProperty", { 
        reduce(classes, 0) { prev,next in 
          (next as? MyClass).map { max(prev,$0.someProperty) } ?? prev 
        }
    }),
    ("Using plain ol' for loop", {
        var maxSoFar = 0
        for obj in classes {
            if let mc = obj as? MyClass {
                maxSoFar = max(maxSoFar, mc.someProperty)
            }
        }
        return maxSoFar
    }),
]

println("\n".join(map(runs, timeRun)))
```

Output from this on my machine:

```
Using AnyObj.someProperty       4115µs, produced 4294310151
Using MyClass.someProperty      1169µs, produced 4294310151
Using plain ol' for loop        1178µs, produced 4294310151
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't reproduce your exact example, but you can try moving away the filter. The following code should be functionally equivalent to your last attempt.

```
var extremes4 = reduce(subviews, startValues) {
    $1 is T2GCell ? (min($0.lowest, $1.tag), max($0.highest, $1.tag)) : $0
}
```

Thus you don't iterate twice on subviews. Notice I removed `lazy` since it appears you always use the entire list.

By the way, IMHO, functional programming can be a very useful approach, but I would think twice before sacrificing code clarity for the only purpose of a *fancy functional approach*. Thus if a for loop is clearer, and even faster ... just use it ;-) That said, is good for you to experiment with different ways to approach the same problem.

Comment: It's a matter of taste, but to my mind, using reduce is much clearer (once the filter is removed) than a for loop, because once you're used to reading it, the intent of reduce is clear, whereas to understand the for loop you essentially need to compile and run it in your head.

Comment: I agree with the metter of taste. I would add the metter of _team_. In case you are working in a team, you might have to consider that not everyone is used to `reduce` and the like. Thus in this case it can become some kind of trade off. Andy Matuschak gave a pretty talk about this topic.

Comment: We are not talking about getting people to use applicative functors or explaining monads here.  Learning about map and reduce is pretty much fundamental to learning Swift.  And once learned, it pays big dividends in terms of making the intent of code clearer.  I don't think the takeaway from Andy's talk should be "best stick with for loops, anything else is too much for some people".

Comment: Totally agree ... too sad we are going a bit off topic here ;-)

Answer (score 0):

One issue I could think of is that the looping is done twice. First the filter returns an filtered array and then a looping in reduce.

> filter(_:)
>
> **Returns an array** containing the elements of the array for which a provided closure indicates a match.
>
> Declaration
>
> func filter(includeElement: (T) -> Bool) -> [T]
>
> Discussion
>
> Use this method to return a new array by filtering an existing array. The closure that you supply for includeElement: should return a Boolean value to indicate whether an element should be included (true) or excluded (false) from the final collection:

While in the second case there is only one loop.

I am not sure if there is any difference of execution time for 'is' as 'as?' operator.